# How to save files with File API to a user-selected location in Android 11?

Tags: android, save, file-permissions, storage-access-framework, android-11

I am very confused with `Scoped Storage` and `Storage Access Framework` (SAF) and all restrictions.. I need to use `File API`, not `Uri`, so:
Android API level <= 29 (Android 10) save to `/storage/emulated/0` works (with `requestLegacyExternalStorage`).
Android API level = 30 (Android 11) save to `/storage/emulated/0` does not work (`IOException: Operation not permitted`).

`Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` is deprecated. OK, so `getExternalFilesDirs()` In Android 11:

```
ctx.getExternalFilesDirs(): /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/<package name>/files //External storage in internal memory
ctx.getExternalFilesDirs(): /storage/16F4-3A1C/Android/data/<package name>/files //SDcard
```

works, because it's app's storage. But users want to have app's folder in root of external storage `/storage/emulated/0/MySpecificFolder` or sdcard `/storage/16F4-3A1C/MySpecificFolder`. I am working with `File API` which should be functional again (unlike Android10).

How can I write to user specific directory, for example to `/storage/emulated/0/MySpecificFolder`?

I tried to use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE);
startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_FOLDER);
```

which open File manager. User creates new directory (because root can't use): `/storage/emulated/0/MySpecificFolder`. Next I am trying create a new file via:

```
File nomedia = new File("/storage/emulated/0/MySpecificFolder", ".nomedia");
if (!nomedia.exists()) {
    nomedia.createNewFile();
}
```

but it's not working `IOException: Operation not permitted`. There is probably problem with write permission.

This line works:

```
DocumentFile newFile = pickedDir.createFile("text/plain", "My Novel");
```

which works with `Uri`. **Why is it not possible to use `File API`?** When I call `createFile()` which uses `Uri`, that's working, but when I call `createNewFile()` which uses `File API`, that's not working. So user can select own directory, but only when app working with `Uri`?

How to get `path` (for later use with `File API`) from SAF, not only `Uri`.

```
// Get Uri from Storage Access Framework.
Uri treeUri = data.getData();
DocumentFile pickedDir = DocumentFile.fromTreeUri(this, treeUri);
Log.i(TAG, "Tree uri: "+treeUri.getPath());  //returns /tree/primary:My
Log.i(TAG, "Picked dir: "+pickedDir.getUri().getPath()); //returns /tree/primary:My/document/primary:My
```

I need use `File API`, because app. creates video+photo+data files which need to be together.

Question: Is it possible for user to choose own path + create folder (via SAF probably) and return `File` (file descriptor) of new created folder by user to app?

Comment: "I need use File API, because app. creates video+photo+data files which need to be together" -- create those files in `getFilesDir()`, then copy them to the user's chosen document tree. Or, choose SDKs that let you work with streams rather than files. "Is it possible for user to choose own path + create folder (via SAF probably) and return File (file descriptor) of new created folder by user to app?" -- not a `File`. You can get file descriptors for a `Uri` via `ContentResolver`.

Comment: Maybe this is what you need: https://github.com/anggrayudi/SimpleStorage

Answer (score 0):

On Android 11 every app can just write to the public directories on external storage using the old File classes.

Dont let the user choose a location as then for further actions you need yo use SAF.

If you want to let the user choose between Documents, Download, Alarms, DCIM, Pictures and so on use a small list with an Alert Builder.